# Trouble adding children using Rest api(Casablanca c++) in firebase

Tags: c++, rest, sdk, firebase, casablanca

Using POST method it inserts a randomkey as child. I just want "Name: Sudarshan" to be the child of UserList.

Can anyone point at what am doing wrong here.

```
return pplx::create_task([]
  {
    json::value postData;
    std::string MY_JSON = "{  \"Name\": \"Sudarshan\"  }";
        postData = json::value::parse(utility::conversions::to_string_t(MY_JSON)); 
    http_client client(L"xxx.firebaseio.com/users/UserList.json");
    string_t PathQueryFragment = L"";
    return client.request(methods::POST, PathQueryFragment,
             postData.to_string().c_str(),
                         L"application/json");
  }).then([](http_response response)
  {
    if(response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
      auto body = response.extract_string();  
      //return std::stoi(body.get().c_str());
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

[Image](http://postimg.org/image/xbxhlfyvl/)

Answer (score 0):

The POST request automatically creates a chronologically incremental key name for you. If you want a specific key name, do a PUT request instead.